# Speech to Text / Voice Recognition on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I am creating an app that requires speech to text functionality.  I have done some research, but have not found a definitive answer :-/.  Has anyone done this on Windows Phone?  Is there an API / web service that I can use?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've seen this done in a number of apps.
There are [various web based services that provide this](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=speech%20to%20text%20api), but nothing built into the phone.